# Using Map instead of For?

Tags: performance-tuning, map

Since i am new to mathematica i tried to do some code with several for-loops. However i saw that mathematica is not efficient with for loops and discovered some functions like map etc. So my question is whether it is possible to replace my for loops with map or something similar in order to boost the performence. Here is the code:

```
For[t = 0, t <= zeit, t++,
 For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
   For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, For[l = 1, l <= L, l++,
      Subscript[summands, l] = 
        coefmat[[i, l]]*coefmat[[j, l]]*
         Exp[-I*(Subscript[Z, l] - Subscript[W, i])*t];]; 
     Subscript[f, i, j] = Sum[Subscript[summands, p], {p, 1, L}];
     ClearAll[summands];];];
```

coefmat are already predifined matrix elements and z_l,W_i are also already defined numbers. In the end i need the f coefficients for a matrix: `\[CapitalOmega] = Table[Subscript[f, i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]`
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It seems like you're multiplying matrices. Did you already look up `Dot[]`?

Comment: Hey not multiplying matrices. Those are just coeficients of a matrix and therefore numbers.

Comment: To write more idiomatic Mathematica code, the first step (for a beginner) is to forget that `For` even exists.  You don't need it.  For standard `i=1..n` loops, use `Do`.  Next realize, that three nested `Do`s can be replaced by a single `Do` with three iterators.  Next, you will notice that since you're just collecting values in $f_{i,j}$, you might as well use a `Table` and get a proper matrix as the result (instead of this subscript structure).  If you also make `Z` and `W` proper vectors (i.e. lists), then it will become clear if this whole thing can be written in terms of ...

Comment: ... vector operations (either element-wise arithmetic or matrix and vector multiplications).   Vector operations are the fastest (faster than `Map`).  And once again, as a beginner, *never ever* use `For`!  `For` is really not needed. Most of the time it's just used like a less convenient and more error prone `Do`, and the other times `While` is just as good anyway.  And `For` makes it harder to transition to idiomatic Mathematica.

Comment: Hey thanks. I will think it through and come back later ;)

Comment: @user3481380 Take a look [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3qp0r0ex2ryuxr/rewrite.nb?dl=0).  I didn't test any of these and I may easily have made a mistake.  It's meant to illustrate the principle.

Comment: Man youu are great. thanks for the effort. I was doing the same thing at the moment. I will test it in a moment and then maybe comeback just in case. Thanks so far!!!

Comment: Ok it worked. The speed increased but something strange happens. For n=128 my comp needs 21 secs. If i double n the time it consumes should take n³ time more (since my L in the sum is also defined by L=1,5*n). But it takes much more time than n³. Thats strange.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nozg2vfxy3tl7mo/Final.nb?dl=0
I think i did everything in the right order but eitherway thanks man. You are a great help!!

Comment: I forgot to add your last line of improvement now everything is aweome!!!! 
Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Szabolcs I never really figured out what's procedural and what's functional.  Is `Table` actually functional?  I thought anything that requires iterators is procedural.  This includes `For`, `Do`, `Sum`, `Product`, and also `Table`.  Do correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @QuantumDot My understanding is that the main difference is side effects.  In functional programming we have "functions" that are analogs of functions in a mathematical sense: they return an output which is fully determined by the input.  "Running" the program means computing the functions.  In procedural programming running a piece of code has an effect mainly through its side effect, i.e. "something happens".  `Do[a+=i, {i,10}]` returns `Null`, the return value is not important.  What's important is that the value of `a` has changed (side effect).  Contrast to `Total@Table[i, {i,10}]`.